# Need to give edit access for all custom object record to same profile but different role

Tags: profile, roles, access

I have one custom object with private OWD and CRUD/View All on profile.
There are more than 10 different roles but not in same role hierarchy and I just need to provide edit to all the records for same profile.

NOTE: I can't give modify all access on PROFILE as it will give Delete access to all the users which I don't want.

Comment: I would suggest to go with a permission set or public groups here. You can always automate the assignment and unassigning part via flow or trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share by profile. Instead, you'll want to create a Public Group, assign all users you wish to share with to the Public Group, then creating a Sharing Rule to share all records with that group (Role: All Users Shared With Group: Edit Custom Object Records).